# JavaScript set input value in while loop

Tags: javascript

The code is below:

```
v1 = document.getElementById('double').value;
while (v1 < 10) {
    v1++;               
    now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + 1000){}
    document.getElementById('inputArea').value = v1;
}
```

inputArea is a text box has one number, I want to increase that number by one ever second until it reaches 10.
The problem is the inputArea only shows the last value 10, it supposed to be ....7, 8, 9 10.

Comment: So, you need `setInterval`, not `while`.

Comment: you also need to `parseInt`.

Comment: While loops are blocking operations.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I know setInterval works, but what I am confused is why it doesn't work in while loop? why it blocks operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to move the value update inside the while loop:

```
v1 = document.getElementById('double').value;
while (v1 < 10) {
    v1++;               
    now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + 1000) {
        document.getElementById('inputArea').value = v1;
    }
}
```

In response to the question in your comment, the reason it doesn't appear to work in the while loop (aside from the above) is because the loop is applying the value update continuously, not giving browser window the chance to update.  Using setInterval avoids this.

Regardless, if you want to see the above working, you could pause the execution of the while loop with something like an alert - this should give the window an opportunity to update.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q9ex60x/).

Answer (score 2):

You can to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

```js
var timerId = setInterval(function(){
  v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('double').value,10);
  if(v1 == 10){
    clearInterval(timerId)
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('double').value = (v1+1)
  }
},1000);
```

```html
<input id="double" value="1" />
```

Comment: Instead of reading the value each time from DOM, you can take advantage of _local_ variable. One way => set to DOM, don't read it. Because, DOM operations are costly.

Comment: @Tushar You *could* do, and I agree in principal. Except a) This looks like a fairly inexperienced javascripter, and I wanted to keep it super simple and b) I dont think reading the value of one field 10 times is going to break any performance metrics ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function. Try calling it recursively with one second increments.

update:

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) might be even better, as then you do not need to deal with recursive calls. Try code similar to one below:

```
v1 = document.getElementById('double').value;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() { 
  v1++;
  document.getElementById('inputArea').value = v1;
  if(v1 === 10) clearInterval(intervalId);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: setInterval is probably more desirable in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done really easy with `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function repeat(i){
   document.getElementById('inputArea').value = i;
   if(i < 10) setTimeout(repeat, 1000, i++);
}, 1000, Number(document.getElementById('double').value));
```